# Free MP3 divide (cut) software for Mac?

Tags: macos, mp3, ipod

I use Mac OS X 10.5. I'd like to divide some bigger mp3 files into several smaller ones. (e.g. divide one track that is 9:29 min long into 13 tracks that are all about 30 sec - 1:10 sec long).

Please, do you know a free software for that?

[I've already tried to trim it with iTunes (options - start time, stop time - create mp3 version), but it didn't work - I need several new tracks.

And I've already tried audacity where it would be possible too, but it was too complicated for me; I am looking for an easier and faster to use software.]

Comment: its easy use the online tool [mp3-cut](http://magicode.me/mp3-cut)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have found, [Audacity is available for Mac OS X](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

I answered a similar question for another user here on dividing tracks with some screen shots, which might help you with understanding it: [MP3 Slice Repetitive Lines](https://superuser.com/questions/58183/mp3-slice-repetitive-lines/58395#58395).

In essence, you can click and drag to select parts of the tune, then paste and save into a new track. It is well worth investing a bit of time into the learning curve. Once you get it, you will find it very fast and easy.

Here is a picture that I hope will help:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it again. The copy and paste function didn't work before and right now I figured out why: It was set on PAUSE (I'd played the track and paused where I wanted it to cut) and it only seems to work if set to STOP.. I have to go right now but will tell you if I could do it in a few hours time. :)

Comment: Your are welcome, Hope it works for you. thanks for the votes

Answer (score 1):

Would [mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php) work?

Answer (score 0):

Garageband can edit unprotected MP3 files.

Comment: It's not exactly free.